# TreeView connect to Multiple Visibility (ContentControl/ListView/etc..) in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a TreeView connected to a ListView and a ContentControl. When we click on a node, that put the Visibility to Hidden or Visible. I already code that and it's working, but it's on MVVM so I want to convert it, and I do not know how.

Code I have already:

```
private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            String tmp = ((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Header.ToString();
            Console.Write(tmp);
            if (tmp == "Lecteur")
            {
                Console.Write("Lecteur\n");
                MediaPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Bibliotheque.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if (tmp == "Bibliotheque")
            {
                Console.Write("Bibliotheque\n");
                MediaPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Bibliotheque.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

If you have an idea, binding all Visibility of ContentControl/ListView or other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the **UI** using triggers, you don't need any extra logic in the codebehind or in the ViewModel

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TrV">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Lecteur"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Bibliotheque"/>                   
    </TreeView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TrV,Path=SelectedItem.Header}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <system:String>Lecteur</system:String>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
        <ListViewItem Content="Lv_One"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Lv_Two"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Lv_Three"/>
    </ListView>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="2" >
        <MediaElement.Style>
            <Style TargetType="MediaElement">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TrV,Path=SelectedItem.Header}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <system:String>Bibliotheque</system:String>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MediaElement.Style>
    </MediaElement>       
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, between i just invert both value of visibility.